# Exceptions in Python(multiple try blocks)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I have been wondering if you can do something like this in python.

```
try:
   something():
if it throws an exception then try this:
   something1():
if it throws an exception again:
   print(exception)
```

Comment: You can put a `try` block inside another `try` block, or in an `except` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

```
try:
    something()
except Exception as exp:
    try:
        something1()
    except Exception as exp2:
        print(exp, exp2)
        raise exp # in case you want to raise the original exception
```